# I've started to make a program in python using multithreading but when i run the code says a error

Tags: python-3.4

```
from _thread import*
from time import*
from tkinter import*
timer = 60
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
output = Label(root,text=timer)

def thread1(timer):
for i in range(59):
    sleep(1)
    output.config(text=timer)
    root.update()
    timer-=1

def thread2():
    for i in range(20):
        text = input('What is your name.\n>>>')
        print('Nice to meet you '+text+'.')


start_new_thread(thread1,(timer,))
start_new_thread(thread2,())
output.pack()
```

[here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzkIP.png)

my question is where am i going wrong
I've tried thread1 function with a thread and it works.

Comment: all code that interacts with tkinter objects needs to be in the same thread.

Comment: First of all, you should indent the contents of your first function.